# Is this correct - Rs.1 is equal to 1 paisa

Tags: arithmetic

yesterday got a SMS, and can any one explain it....

```
One Re= 100ps 
=10ps x10ps (Notice the how the equation goes haywire from here) 
=0.1Re X0.1Re 
=0.01Re 
= 1 paisa

confused... can any one explain it...
```

Comment: You can't factor an equation with units like that - you end up squaring the conversion factor between ps and Re.

Comment: $100$ ps $\neq 10$ ps $\times 10$ ps, $100$ ps $= 10$ $\times 10$ ps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dimensionally, $$100ps\ne10ps\times10ps=100(ps)^2\\0.01Re\ne0.1Re\times0.1Re=0.01(Re)^2$$

So,

$$1 Re= 100ps 
=10 \times10\; ps
=10 \times0.1\;Re =1 Re\\
\boxed{1Re 
= 100 ps}$$

Comment: thank you so much #adithya